# Symfony Form - Add required fields to form depending on other field value

Tags: symfony

I want to add some required fields to my form when an other field has some value. I've tried to do it with `PRE_SET_DATA` event but I cannot get data in my event.

My example here is to add partner name field when a user is married.

**My UserType**

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('familyStatus', ChoiceType::class, [
                'label' => 'Statut de famille',
                'label_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'fg-label'
                ],
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'sc-gqjmRU fQXahQ'
                ],
                'required' => true,
                'choices' => [
                    'Married' => 'M',
                    'Single' => 'S'
                ]
            ])
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
                $form = $event->getForm();
                $user = $event->getData();
                $status = $user->getFamilyStatus(); // Give me NULL
                //$status = $form->get('familyStatus')->getData() Give me NULL too


                /*
                if ($user && $status === 'M') {
                    $form->add('partnerName', TextType::class, [
                        'required' => true,
                        'mapped' => false
                   ]);
                )
                */
            })
        ;
    }
```

What's wrong ? How can I add dynamically new fields depending on other field ?
I also tried with POST_SET_DATA but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the second example from this part of the docs [link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms).

Basically you set the event listener to the entire form. You should add another listener to the field itself with POST_SUBMIT event.