# Symfony Dynamic Form - Get file from embedded form gives NULL

Tags: symfony

I have a dynamic form which display/hide a `FileType` field depending on another field value ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62138143/symfony-form-add-required-fields-to-form-depending-on-other-field-value)).
When i'm trying to get the file in my controller, it always gives me `NULL`

**My UserType:**

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('familyStatus', ChoiceType::class, [
                'label' => 'Statut de famille',
                'label_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'fg-label'
                ],
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'sc-gqjmRU fQXahQ'
                ],
                'required' => true,
                'choices' => [
                    'Married' => 'M',
                    'Single' => 'S'
                ]
            ]);

        $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, $status = null) {
            if ($status === 'M') {
                $form->add('familyInfo', FamilyInfoType::class);
            }
        };

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                $user = $event->getData();
                $formModifier($event->getForm(), $user->getFamilyStatus());
            }
        );

        $builder->get('familyStatus')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                $status = $event->getForm()->getData();
                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $status);
            }
        );

    }
```

**My FamilyInfoType:**

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('partnerName', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Nom du partenaire',
                'label_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'fg-label'
                ],
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'sc-gqjmRU fQXahQ'
                ],
                'required' => true
            ])
            ->add('weddingProof', FileType::class, [
                'label' => 'Acte de mariage',
                'label_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'Upload-label'
                ],
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'Upload-input',
                    'maxsize'     =>'4M',
                    'accept'      =>'image/*'
                ],
                'required' => false,
                'mapped' => false
            ]);
    }
```

**My UserController:**

```
    /**
     * @Route("/user", name="add_user", methods={"GET", "POST"})
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function addUser(Request $request) {
        $response = [];

        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            if ($user->getFamilyStatus() === 'M') {
                var_dump("ok");

                $document = $form->get('familyInfo')->get('weddingProof')->getData();
                $partnerName = $form->get('familyInfo')->get('partnerName')->getData();

                var_dump($document); // NULL
                var_dump($partnerName); // OK the value is displayed
                die;
            }
        }

        return $this->render("user/registration.html.twig", ['form' => $form->createView()]);
   }
```

It's working with `TextType` field but not with `FileType`. What's wrong with my form.

Comment: Is the form submitted via Ajax or standard way?

Comment: Yes I use Ajax to display/hide additional fields (in FamilyInfoType class).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the mapped => false option to the file type. The form is not setting the uploaded file object in the property of your entity because it’s not mapped.